# CSS don't allow breaking elements of a div on to new line

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with some dynamically generated content, on that page I have a big div (We'll call this the container) containing other divs (We'll call these groups), each of these divs (Groups) contains a number of input fields. (How many is not known in advance, but I could limit it to something like 1-10).

I need every input in a group on the same line, so no linebreaks (If that term is correct in this context) in a group. There can be as many groups as fit in one line, but the first input on a new line always needs to be the first input in that group.

Currently I have most of that working, except for the whole line breaking thing. Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vc5y.png) of the current situation.

As you can see, the groups are broken up, the last 3 inputs on the first line should already be on the next line.

Is there a way to disable this line breaking behaviour for all elements in a div while maintaining the ability to break up multiple of these div's?

Here is an example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/osomeonsoikdfja/pen/gOapNZG).

Here is the css I have so far:

```
.number-fields input {
    width: 1cm;
    text-align: center;
}

.number-fields-input {
    margin: 5px;
}

* {
    background-color: #2F363F;
}

.form-control {
    color: lightcyan;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #2F363F;
}

#number-fields {
    padding-right: 5vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.input_group {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 5vh;
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of your code to the question.

Comment: Please add a  little bit of code to your question.

Comment: @TylerH I have added a link to codepen, is that enough?

Comment: @ArpitSingh I added a link to codepen.

Comment: Technically you need to add a [mcve] to the question, not just a link to an off-site code sandbox. Stack Overflow *does* have a code sandbox tool of its own in the edit view!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using flexbox here with flex-wrap:**wrap** on the container and flex-wrap:**nowrap** on the groups of inputs.

```
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}

.input-group {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}
```